# Calculating Theta(n) of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to calculate Theta(n) of the following algorithm

```
for i = 1 -> n
   for j = 1 -> n
       B[i,j] = findMax(A,i,j)

findMax(A,i,j)
    if j < i
        return 0
    else
        max = A[i]
        for k = i + 1 -> j
             if max < A[k]
                max = A[k]
        return max
```

I know that O, theta, and omega roughly translate to

O ≈ ≤

Ω ≈ ≥

Θ ≈ =

For the algorithm I think that omega = n^2, o = n^3, but i'm not sure what theta would be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you calculate the  number of times the code line

```
if max < A[k]
```

is executed depending on `n` you would get Theta(n^3) executions. Thus the running time of your algorithm is Thetat(n^3) as well.

Comment: So would omega also be n^3?

Answer (score 2):

Theta(n^3). There are n^2 iterations of the nested for loop. Approximately half of these iterations run in O(1) time, when j < i. The other half of these iterations have on average an n/2 difference for j-i, so the other half of the iterations take Theta(n/2) time. Since approximately half of the n^2 iterations take on average n/2 time, n^2/2 * n/2 = n^3/4 = Theta(n^3) time for half of the iterations. The other half of the n^2 iterations take n^2/2 = Theta(n^2) time. Thus total runtime = Theta(n^3).